# Unable to import definitions from submodule package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a project that uses a git submodule to import a python package from a private repository, which is then installed via pip. The structure is something like this:

```
my_project
  _submodules
    prvt_pkg
      prvt_pkg
        lib
          __init__.py
          types.py
        __init__.py
        prvt_pkg.py
      setup.py
      requirements.txt
  app.py
```

(not sure if this makes a difference, but `setup.py` looks like this:

```py
import setuptools
from setuptools import find_packages

with open("readme.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name='prvt_pkg',
    version='0.0.1',
    author='...',
    author_email='...',
    description='...',
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url='...',
    project_urls={
        "Bug Tracker": "..."
    },
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[],
)
```

I am able to import the main class from `prvt_pkg.py` like

```py
from prvt_pkg.prvt_pkg import my_prvt_class
```

however, I would also like to import the pydantic types defined in `_submodules/prvt_pkg/prvt_pkg/lib/types.py` like

```py
from prvt_pkg.lib.types import MyType
```

but PyCharm is telling me that won't work

All of the `__init__.py` files are empty.

Is there a way that I can achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing up this question I found the solution, so decided to post anyway and provide that here.

What ended up fixing the problem was after running `git submodule update --remote --merge` to pull in the changes (including the lib/types.py file), I needed to then run `pip install _submodules/prvt_pkg` again to install the new version.